# Build .Net REST Api (Employee's Salary column ) support two client models - Integer & Float

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-core

I might need understand how to provide solution for this problem statement.

**REST Api**: There is an existing .Net Core Api where Employee records are returned. One of the column is Salary. Currently this Salary field is returned as **Integer** data type as Database table also **Integer**. This column type can be changed to float later to support below requirements.

Here are the two requirement.

**Client 1 (Existing Client should continue use old Api Structure with Int type)**: Existing client wants to deal this Salary field as **Integer** data type and do all CRUD operations as **Integer**. Current .DLL point to old Api version in .DLL which we will not able to change it right now)

**Client 2 (New Client where they can point newer version of Api to support Float type )**: New client wants to deal this Salary field as **Float** data type and do all CRUD operations as **Float** only.

Please suggest.

Comment: Float for money... Terrible idea...

Comment: For money use long format , as it is what supported by Entity framework core and stripe payment services.

Comment: Selvin Yes it is but need solution for this use case

Comment: You provide the API, so you can tell them no. If they want to use floats, they can divide your integers by 100 and store the result in a float.

Comment: But if you really must, you could create new endpoints, or overload your actions with content negotiation (accept: "application/json+ridiculous-floats").

Comment: @CodeCaster Thats impossible, the existing still wanna go with Int type, We only have control on the new clients.

Comment: What is impossible?

Comment: @CodeCaster "telling client no to use old Api which is for Int" is impossible. Because, the Api call is from their .dll , we don't ask them or release new .dll version to use new Api

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If the client to your API is in a DLL which you can't update, why do you want to return a different response? This will break the API. Please [edit] your question to paint the full picture, or we can't help you.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I have edited the question, my question how to modify the current Api to support both old and new client (We dont need two versions of Api)

Answer (score 0):

You do need two versions of your API, because you do not want to use floats for monetary data, ever.

If you're going to change your database column type for one customer's ridiculous request, you're in for a lot of (financial) pain later.

Just tell them they need to do things differently, or if that isn't in your culture, then give them their own API where you translate your ints to floats at the API boundary.

You can do this through content negotiation (recognize their calls by a header like `accept: application/json+floats-for-money`) or though new endpoints.